# JavaScript Objects is not recognised by it's property

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, properties

my program is very simple - it should save movies in array and then print them in JSON format.
The problem is with 'contains()' method (i think). It works well with one-named-movie but it returns null when the name contains spaces. Here is the code.

```js
function movieDirectors(array) {
  let movies = [];

  class Movie {
    constructor(name, director, date) {
      this.name = name;
      this.director = director;
      this.date = date;
    }
  }
  let contains = function (movieName) {
    let movie = null;
    movies.forEach(m => m.name === movieName ? movie = m : movie = null);
    return movie;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let command = array[i].split(' ');

    if (command.includes('addMovie')) {
      let name = command.slice(1, command.length).join(' ');
      movies.push(new Movie(name, null, null));
    } else if (command.includes('directedBy')) {
      let name1 = command.slice(0, command.indexOf('directedBy')).join(' ');
      if (contains(name1) !== null) {
        let movie = contains(name1);
        movie.director = command.slice(command.indexOf('directedBy') + 1, command.length).join(' ');
      }
    } else if (command.includes('onDate')) {
      let name2 = command.slice(0, command.indexOf('onDate')).join(' ');
      if (contains(name2) !== null) {
        let movie = contains(name2);
        movie.date = command.slice(command.indexOf('onDate') + 1, command.length).join(' ');
      }
    }
  }
  movies.forEach(m => m.director != null && m.name != null && m.date != null ? console.log(JSON.stringify(m)) : null);
}

movieDirectors([
    'addMovie Fast and Furious',
    'addMovie Godfather',
    'Godfather directedBy Francis Ford Coppola',
    'Godfather onDate 29.07.2018',
    'Fast and Furious onDate 30.07.2018',
    'Fast and Furious directedBy Rob Cohen']);
```

The output must be this:

```
{"name":"Fast and Furious","date":"30.07.2018","director":"Rob Cohen"}
{"name":"Godfather","director":"Francis Ford Coppola","date":"29.07.2018"}
```

I am very green in JavaScript language and I will be thankful for helping me understand these niceties of the language.

Comment: I don't see how you can allow movie names to have spaces. Consider changing the format of the input array?

Comment: My university has homework check system which has tests (like this one) and that's the reason i can't change the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `contains` is expected to stop and return when found a movie with given name.

It will work:

```js
let contains = function (movieName) {
    return movies.find(m => m.name === movieName);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the way you made the `forEach` inside `contains()`.

You had:

```
movies.forEach(m => m.name === movieName ? movie = m : movie = null);
```

Your `movies` array is populated with `Fast and Furious` first and `Godfather` second. In the first iteration of the forEach, it will test `Fast and Furious` and see it is equal to `movieName`, so `movie = m` your code will set `movie` with the correct object. In the second iteration, it will run the same test with `Godfather`and see it is different from `movieName`, so `movie = null` your code will clear `movie` and that's the mistake. Instead, make your code don't do anything when `m.name === movieName` is false. So:

```
movies.forEach(m => m.name === movieName ? movie = m : null);
```

Here is the full working snippet:

```js
function movieDirectors(array) {
  let movies = [];

  class Movie {
    constructor(name, director, date) {
      this.name = name;
      this.director = director;
      this.date = date;
    }
  }
  let contains = function (movieName) {
    let movie = null;
    movies.forEach(m => m.name === movieName ? movie = m : null); // The problem was here
    return movie;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let command = array[i].split(' ');

    if (command.includes('addMovie')) {
      let name = command.slice(1, command.length).join(' ');
      movies.push(new Movie(name, null, null));
    } else if (command.includes('directedBy')) {
      let name1 = command.slice(0, command.indexOf('directedBy')).join(' ');
      if (contains(name1) !== null) {
        let movie = contains(name1);
        movie.director = command.slice(command.indexOf('directedBy') + 1, command.length).join(' ');
      }
    } else if (command.includes('onDate')) {
      let name2 = command.slice(0, command.indexOf('onDate')).join(' ');
      if (contains(name2) !== null) {
        let movie = contains(name2);
        movie.date = command.slice(command.indexOf('onDate') + 1, command.length).join(' ');
      }
    }
  }
  movies.forEach(m => m.director != null && m.name != null && m.date != null ? console.log(JSON.stringify(m)) : null);
}

movieDirectors([
    'addMovie Fast and Furious',
    'addMovie Godfather',
    'Godfather directedBy Francis Ford Coppola',
    'Godfather onDate 29.07.2018',
    'Fast and Furious onDate 30.07.2018',
    'Fast and Furious directedBy Rob Cohen']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As your problem is mostly related to string parsing, you could solve it with regular expressions like this:

```js
const input = [
  'addMovie Fast and Furious',
  'addMovie Godfather',
  'Godfather directedBy Francis Ford Coppola',
  'Godfather onDate 29.07.2018',
  'Fast and Furious onDate 30.07.2018',
  'Fast and Furious directedBy Rob Cohen'
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const parseAddMovie = /^addMovie\s(.+)/.exec(cur);
    if (parseAddMovie) {
      const [, name] = parseAddMovie;
      acc.push({ name });
      return acc;
    }
    const parseDirectedBy = /(.+)\sdirectedBy\s(.+)/.exec(cur);
    if (parseDirectedBy) {
      const [, name, director] = parseDirectedBy;
      const found = acc.find(x => x.name === name);
      found && (found.director = director);
      return acc;
    }
    const parseOnDate = /(.+)\sonDate\s(.+)/.exec(cur);
    if (parseOnDate) {
      const [, name, date] = parseOnDate;
      const found = acc.find(x => x.name === name);
      found && (found.date = date);
      return acc;
    }
  }, []);

console.log(output);
```